# for loop integrated in a normal function

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

How can I integrate a for-loop in a normal function?

e.g. `function(x,y,z){ for(i in i:1200){test<-(x-i)+y+(z-i)}}`

Why doesn´t it work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the created value. Also for multiple values to be returned, test must be a vector:

```
myfn <- function(x,y,z){ 
    test = NULL
    for(i in 1:1200)
        {test[i]<-(x-i)+y+(z-i)}
    test
}
```

Otherwise only the last value of test will be returned.

The i:1200 error has to be corrected as suggested by @beginneR

Comment: @beginnerR: That did not seem the only error. I have edited my answer.